# Ansible -- Using Conditionals from Ec2 Tags in Dynamic Inventory

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-inventory

I am using ec2 dynamic inventory.

All of my ec2 instances are tagged with their environment. So for example `tag:env = prod` or `tag:env = test`

**So my dynamic inventory has variables set properly....**

```
  "ec2": [
    "ip_10_1_1_1_ec2_internal",
    "ip_10_1_1_2_ec2_internal",
    "ip_10_1_1_3_ec2_internal",
    "ip_10_1_1_4_ec2_internal",
    "ip_10_1_1_5_ec2_internal",
    "ip_10_1_1_6_ec2_internal",
    "ip_10_1_1_7_ec2_internal"
  ],

...

  "tag_env_mgmt": [
    "ip_10_1_1_7_ec2_internal",
    "ip_10_1_1_6_c2_internal",
    "ip_10_1_1_5_ec2_internal"
  ],
  "tag_env_prod": [
    "ip_10_1_1_2_ec2_internal",
    "ip_10_1_1_1_ec2_internal"
  ],
  "tag_env_stage": [
    "ip_10_1_1_3_ec2_internal",
    "ip_10_1_1_4_ec2_internal"
  ],
```

So I now want to set conditionals based on certain tags. **Here is the type of playbook conditionals I want to use, adding users only if the tag is "stage":**

```
---
- hosts: ec2
  vars:
    users:
    - user1
    - user2
  tasks:
  - name: "Create user accounts and add users to groups"
    user:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      groups: "sudo"
    with_items: "{{ users }}"
    when: tag_env_stage is defined
```

Also tried it like this:

```
  - name: "Create user accounts and add users to groups"
    user:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      groups: "sudo"
    with_items: "{{ users }}"
    when: tag_env_stage
```

and this:

```
  - name: "Create user accounts and add users to groups"
    user:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      groups: "sudo"
    with_items: "{{ users }}"
    when: tag_env == stage
```

The plays fail to execute. I get errors along the lines of:

> error while evaluating conditional (tag_env_stage):

I checked the documentation and didn't see anything sticking out at me.

(https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html)

(https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tag_env_prod`, `tag_env_stage` are group names in your example.

You can use:

```
when: ('tag_env_stage' in group_names)
```

But this is a bit ugly. I'd recommend to use modern Ansible version with support of inventory plugins (instead of legacy dynamic inventories). If your inventory is generated with `aws_ec2` plugin, you have direct access to `tags` variable. And so you can use:

```
when: tags['env'] == 'stage'
```

Comment: Wait. Dynamic inventory is deprecated??  

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html

Comment: Not yet. But I bet they won't stay for long. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory.html#enabling-inventory-plugins

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it working with the following syntax.

`when: hostvars[inventory_hostname].ec2_tag_env == "stage"`

As the other answer mentioned, I was trying to use `group_names` which are not actually identifiers of the instances themselves. @Konstantin's answer provides how to deal with `group_names` so I needed to use `hostvars` object from dynamic inventory.